# c# creating excel sheet silently and saving data

Tags: c#, excel-2010

I have created a server to which multiple clients connect and they send some hex data to the server. The data is processed by the server and I want to save this data in excel sheet. I am using the following code but this one opens the excel file every time, writes the data to it and close it. Also the excel file should already exist.

```
public class CreateExcelDoc
{

    private static Excel.Workbook workbook = null;

    private static Excel.Worksheet worksheet = null;
    private static Excel.Range workSheet_range = null;
    private static Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
private static Excel.Workbooks workbooks = app.Workbooks;
    public static void createDoc()
    {
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        try
        {
            workbook = workbooks.Open("C:\\Documents and Settings\\pratyush\\Desktop\\test.xlsx", misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);


            app.Visible = true;
            worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write("Error");
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }

    public static void createHeaders(int row, int col, string htext, string cell1, string cell2, int mergeColumns, string b, bool font, int size, string fcolor)
    {
        worksheet.Cells[row, col] = htext;
        workSheet_range = worksheet.get_Range(cell1, cell2);
        workSheet_range.Merge(mergeColumns);
        switch (b)
        {
            case "YELLOW":
                workSheet_range.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow.ToArgb();
                break;
            case "GRAY":
                workSheet_range.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Gray.ToArgb();
                break;
            case "GAINSBORO":
                workSheet_range.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Gainsboro.ToArgb();
                break;
            case "Turquoise":
                workSheet_range.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Turquoise.ToArgb();
                break;
            case "PeachPuff":
                workSheet_range.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.PeachPuff.ToArgb();
                break;
            default:
                //  workSheet_range.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color..ToArgb();
                break;

        }

        workSheet_range.Borders.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black.ToArgb();
        workSheet_range.Font.Bold = font;
        workSheet_range.ColumnWidth = size;
        if (fcolor.Equals(""))
        {
            workSheet_range.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.White.ToArgb();
        }
        else
        {
            workSheet_range.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black.ToArgb();
        }

    }
    public static void addData(int row, int col, string data, string cell1, string cell2, string format)
    {
        worksheet.Cells[row, col] = data;
        workSheet_range = worksheet.get_Range(cell1, cell2);
        workSheet_range.Borders.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black.ToArgb();
        workSheet_range.NumberFormat = format;
    }

    public static void adddata()
    {
        createDoc();

        //creates the main header
        createHeaders(5, 2, "Total of Products", "B5", "D5", 2, "YELLOW", true, 10, "n");
        //creates subheaders
        createHeaders(6, 2, "Sold Product", "B6", "B6", 0, "GRAY", true, 10, "");


        //add Data to to cells
        addData(7, 2, "114287", "B7", "B7", "#,##0");


        workbook.Close(true, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
        app.Quit();


    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        adddata();
    }
}
}
```

What I want is that my server should create new excel file whose name is client ip address silently and add data to it after it has been processed by the server and save it silently. How can I achieve this since currently my code every time opens the file and save data in the excel file and then closes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can usee [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/). It free and more efficient than Interop.

Delete the file if it exists aready, and create new,  and do whatever you want.

```
FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(fileName);
if (newFile.Exists)
 File.Delete(fileName);
ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile);
..... //work with worksheets
pck.Save();
```

You can find complete sample on the EPPlus website.